# iOS Splash Page while Loading Data

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to write an app that displays a simple logo/splash page while the app retrieves some data. I cannot seem to find a tutorial anywhere.

I have a "MainWindow.xib" file that will have my splash page, and I'm setting that as my "Main Interface" in my Info.plist, however, I cannot seem to see how to replace that page with a .xib that contains a UINavigationController. I thought I would just create a new UIController, that had a UINavigationController and in my .xib I'll drag in a Navigation Controller and set all my information, but it's giving me real fits.

So, I figured I would have a UIController that I would "alloc" and "init" with my second .xib that contains all my navigation.

```
myMainController = [[UIController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainNavController":nil];
```

in "MainNavController.xib", I've dragged in a Navigation Controller, but I don't know what to connect it to????

I'm sure I'm going down the wrong, path; but I cannot find a decent tutorial for this.

Can someone give direction or link to a decent tutorial?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you ever actually adding the new controller to your existing view?  If not, something like:

```
[self.view addSubview:myMainController.view];
```

should do it for you.  A better alternative is likely to be:

```
self.window.rootViewController = myMainController;
```

But I'm fairly new to this and maybe I've missed something ...

Comment: @El Guapo I almost never (ok, really, never) use the interface builder, so I guess I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to do or maybe when you're trying to do it (I know, I know, I should learn more about using interface builder).  But, when are you having the problem?  You described it as waiting for the data to load, so I assumed that you were creating the the "myMainViewController" once the data had finished loading? no?  If so, as soon as you create the controller, assign its view as in my answer above.  Or am I missing something in what you're trying to do?

Comment: Basically... I was going down the path of having a "MainWindow.xib" with a splash page... then I was creating a custom UIViewController that had a nib with a NavigationController, but for some reason switching to the custom UIViewController was not working.

Comment: @El Guapo Without some additional code, I can't understand the problem enough to help.  I think I'd need to see the context around where you are creating the custom uiviewcontroller in the code.

Answer (score 0):

To display a splash screen while the app is loading you can use Default.png image file.
However, I think your question is how to display another splash screen for a period of time after the app has been loaded.
In you MainWindow.xib keep your window separated from your Navigation Controller. Add your splash screen view with an image to the xib.
Make two outlets: one for slash view, one for Navigation Controller.

```
IBOutlet UIView* _spashScreenView;
IBOutlet UINavigationController* _navigationController;
```

In applicationDidFinishLaunching method add your splash screen view to the window.

```
[_window addSubview:_spashScreenView];
// lay it out
```

When you are ready to display your navigation controller:

```
[_spashScreenView removeFromSuperView];
[_window addSubview:_navigationController];
```